# string of undetermined length c

Tags: c, string, string-length

Hi I was trying to create an array of string of an undetermined length in c.
This is my code :

```
    int main()
    {
        int lineCount=linesCount();
        char text[lineCount][10];
        printf("%d",lineCount);
        FILE *  fpointer = fopen("test.txt","r");
        fgets(text,10,fpointer);
        fclose(fpointer);
        printf("%s",text);
        return 0;
    }
```

I would like to replace 10 in

```
    char text[lineCount][10];
```

My code reads out a file I already made the amount of lines dynamic.
Since the line length is unpredictable I would like to replace 10 by a something dynamic.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you make the amount of lines dynamic?  You might be able to use a similar approach for the characters in a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this cleanly, we want a `char *` array rather than an 2D `char` array:

```
char *text[lineCount];
```

And, we need to use memory from the heap to store the individual lines.

Also, don't "hardwire" so called "magic" numbers like `10`. Use an `enum` or `#define` (e.g) `#define MAXWID 10`. Note that with the solution below, we obviate the need for using the magic number at all.

Also, note the use of `sizeof(buf)` below instead of a magic number.

And, we want [separate] loops when reading and printing.

Anyway, here's the refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
linesCount(void)
{

    return 23;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int lineCount = linesCount();
    char *text[lineCount];
    char buf[10000];

    printf("%d", lineCount);

    // open file and _check_ the return
    const char *file = "test.txt";
    FILE *fpointer = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fpointer == NULL) {
        perror(file);
        exit(1);
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fpointer) != NULL) {
        // strip newline
        buf[strcspn(buf,"\n")] = 0;

        // store line -- we must allocate this
        text[i++] = strdup(buf);
    }

    fclose(fpointer);

    for (i = 0;  i < lineCount;  ++i)
        printf("%s\n", text[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The above code is derived from your original code. But, it assumes that the `linesCount` function can predict the number of lines. And, it doesn't check against overflow of the fixed length `text` array.

Here is a more generalized version that will allow an arbitrary number of lines with varying line lengths:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int lineCount = 0;
    char **text = NULL;
    char buf[10000];

    // open file and _check_ the return
    const char *file = "test.txt";
    FILE *fpointer = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fpointer == NULL) {
        perror(file);
        exit(1);
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fpointer) != NULL) {
        // strip newline
        buf[strcspn(buf,"\n")] = 0;

        ++lineCount;

        // increase number of lines in array
        text = realloc(text,sizeof(*text) * lineCount);
        if (text == NULL) {
            perror("realloc");
            exit(1);
        }

        // store line -- we must allocate this
        text[lineCount - 1] = strdup(buf);
    }

    fclose(fpointer);

    // print the lines
    for (i = 0;  i < lineCount;  ++i)
        printf("%s\n", text[i]);

    // more processing ...

    // free the lines
    for (i = 0;  i < lineCount;  ++i)
        free(text[i]);

    // free the list of lines
    free(text);

    return 0;
}
```